# C++ structures containing structures SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, structure, segmentation-fault

Let me paste the code first

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#define MAX 100

using namespace std;

int index;

struct node{
    int key;
    struct node *up;
    int rank;
};

struct edge{
    struct node *start, *end;
    int weight;
};

struct graf{
    struct node *tops[MAX];
    int topsAmount;
    struct edge *edges[MAX];
    int edgesAmount;
};

void makeSet(struct node *z, int key){
    z->up = z;
    z->rank = 0;
    z->key = key;
}

struct node *findSet(struct node *x){
    if(x!=x->up)
        x->up = findSet(x->up);
    return x->up;
};

struct node *returnPath(struct node *x){
    cout<<"klucz: "<<x->key<<" ranga: "<<x->rank<<endl;
    if(x!=x->up)
        {
            returnPath(x->up);
        }
}

void link(struct node *x, struct node *y){
    if(x->rank>y->rank)
    {
        y->up=x;
    }
    else
    {
        x->up=y;
        if(x->rank == y->rank)
            y->rank++;
    }
}

void unionFun(struct node *x, struct node *y){
    link(findSet(x), findSet(y));
}

bool acompare(edge lhs, edge rhs) { return lhs.weight < rhs.weight; }

struct edge *MSTKruskal(struct graf *G){
    struct edge *A = new edge[MAX];
    index=0;
    for(int i=0; i<G->topsAmount; i++)
    {
        makeSet(G->tops[i],0);
    }
    sort(G->edges[0], G->edges[G->edgesAmount-1], acompare);
    for(int i=0; i<G->edgesAmount; i++)
    {
        if(findSet(G->edges[i]->start) != findSet(G->edges[i]->end))
        {
            A[index].start = G->edges[i]->start;
            A[index].end = G->edges[i]->end;
            A[index].weight = G->edges[i]->weight;
            index++;
            unionFun(G->edges[i]->start, G->edges[i]->end);
        }
    }
    return A;
}


int main()
{

    struct node *values[11];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        values[i] = new node;
        makeSet(values[i],i);
    }
    unionFun(values[0], values[1]);
    unionFun(values[2], values[3]);
    unionFun(values[1], values[2]);
    unionFun(values[5], values[6]);
    unionFun(values[7], values[8]);
    unionFun(values[3], values[5]);
    unionFun(values[0], values[7]);
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout<<"sciezka klucza "<<i<<endl;
        returnPath(values[i]);
    }

    struct graf *Graf = new graf;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        Graf->tops[i] = values[i];
        Graf->topsAmount++;
    }

    struct edge *Edges = new edge[4];
    Edges[0].start = values[1];
    Edges[1].start = values[2];
    Edges[2].start = values[3];
    Edges[3].start = values[4];
    Edges[0].end = values[5];
    Edges[1].end = values[6];
    Edges[2].end = values[7];
    Edges[3].end = values[8];
    Edges[0].weight = 10;
    Edges[1].weight = 12;
    Edges[2].weight = 11;
    Edges[3].weight = 13;

    Graf->edges[0] = Edges[0]; //this line was deleted after I found out that I can't compile it
    Graf->edges[0]->weight = 0;


    return 0;
}
```

I want to set new graf so firstly in for loop I add tops to my structure and it works then I want to add edges and problem appears. I thought I can just create another array of structures edge and then just set same array in Graf on same values (`Graf->edges[0] = Edges[0];` last lines of the code) but it didn't compile, so I wanted to set every value of structure edge in array Graf separately (start = start, end = end etc) but debugger shows SIGSEGV on last line (`Graf->edges[0]->weight = 0;`) how can I fix it?

Comment: Why the `c` tag?

Comment: I don't know I thought I use some of C and some of C++

Comment: Something is probably null or uninitialized, use your debugger to examine the data at that line before it executes. As a side note: in C++, `struct` and `class` create a type name and you do not need to repeat the `struct` or `class` keyword when using those types.

Comment: The code here *is not* C (even if your "style" is more C than C++), so the tag does not apply.

Comment: You never allocated memory for Graf->Edges.

Comment: Never mix up C and C++. They have completely different design choices.

Comment: Yeah I know it's just task on my lecture is specified that way, I just have to stick to orders

Answer (score 1):

`Edges[0]` has type `edge`, but `Graf->edges[0]` has type `edge*`, i.e. the types are incompatible, which is why the assignment is not allowed.

You probably want to take the address of `Edges[0]` like so:

```
Graf->edges[0] = &Edges[0];
```

Comment: yeah that solves half of a problem, I'm sure I checked it earlier and it didn't work but now it compiles fine... anyway thank you. Do you know why I can't use `Graf->edges[0]->weight = 0;` to set values?

Comment: Because you never allocated memory for `edges`.